# QuickBooks Online Modify Invoices

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am integrating QuickBooks Online With java . The i want to modify Invoices, Customers and Itemservices. I have successfully done with Itemservices and Customers but when i do it for Invoices i get an error : `statusCode="1030" statusMessage="Not supported"`

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the [QuickBooks OSR](http://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/common/newosr/index.html) (make sure you uncheck US, and check OE), or searched Google for an answer regarding QuickBooks Online InvoiceMod, you'd find that this operation is, in fact, "Not supported".

See:

- [QuickBooks Online qbXML API limitations](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/QuickBooks_Online_via_qbXML#Known_Bugs.2FLimitations_of_QuickBooks_Online_Edition)
- [QuickBooks Online InvoiceMod not supported](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=7&threadid=12484&enterthread=y)

Note that if you're building a SaaS application (software as a service), then you SHOULD NOT be using the qbXML interface. Instead, you should be using the [Intuit Partner Platform](http://developer.intuit.com/), which [doesn't have this limitation](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0050_Data_Services/0400_QuickBooks_Online/Invoice).

Comment: Thanks ... yes i got this that it is not supported ,.. can i use quickbooks partner platform for quickbooks online edition(QBOE)

Comment: can  i use IPP(Intuit Partner Platform) for integration of Quick books Online. ?

Comment: If you are a software as a service application (i.e. you are reselling your software to lots and lots of people) then you can use the Intuit Partner Platform. Otherwise, you can't.